# javascript capture and tamper http requests

Tags: javascript, security

Is there a way with javascript on a page to tamper http requests done by other scripts (on same page)? The other scripts can be from external domains.

Let's say on a page X a script loaded from an external domain performs an http get like `GET http://www.example.com?foo=bar` is it possible that a previously loaded script in the same page X can capture this request, and tamper with it so it becomes `GET http://www.example.com?foo=qux`?

In jquery i can achieve this by wrapping the ajax get post methods. But is this possible for plain javascript, no frameworks, working across all page and client's http requests?

It seems to me that for this to be done, the script must be able to override something very deep in the core. If i have to **guess i would say it's not possible by design and because of security**. What do you think?

p.s. no proxies, no external tools.

Comment: No, you can't tamper with a browser's HTTP requests.  But you can manipulate the DOM with Javascript and change the values of links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** you can't capture the HTTP request going out of your app, **once it has gone out of your app**.

However, there is one work around possible

1. if you want to alter some parameters **before it goes of your app**,
2. All the other request from your website are **AJAX requests**
3. They are invoking your custom method, say `customAjax()` which can
   alter the parameters of the actual request that will go out.